# ComboBox binding with ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, combobox, observablecollection

I have been tasked with adding a combobox to an already existing WPF form.  I have never worked with WPF and I am pretty lost, specifically when it comes to binding and using the ObservableCollection property.  All the examples are completely different form the way I was told to do it.

I originally had my combobox set up like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="GroupComboBox" Width="132" Height="22" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" >         
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Data Warehouse"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="KPI"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="Failures"></ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="All Groups"></ComboBoxItem>            
</ComboBox>
```

Which worked great.  This was when I was told I had to get rid of all the ComboBoxItem Contents and bind the combo box to ObservableCollectionGroups and ObservableCollectionSelectedGroups and to do so all I had to do was add this to the ViewModel class:

```
 public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; set; }      

 public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedGroups { get; set; }
```

OK, so I added the above to the view model class like this:

```
public class ClioViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Groups { get; set; }      

    public ObservableCollection<string> SelectedGroups { get; set; }
}
```

(there's a ton of other stuff already in this class as well but in the interest of time and space I did not post it.  If needed I will gladly add more if requested)

I then changed my xaml to look like this:

```
<ComboBox Name="GroupComboBox" ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" SelectedItem=" Binding  SelectedGroups, Mode=TwoWay}" Width="132" Height="22" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3" Margin="0,30" VerticalAlignment="Top" >                         
</ComboBox>
```

which didn't work.  Of course it didn't work!  I haven't listed any of the items I want inside of my comboBox!  The question is, if they do not belong inside of the comboBox and they are not put in the Group/Selected group properties, where in the heck do they go?  None of the multitude of combobox binding examples I have seen look anything like what I am being told to do.

If someone could enlighten me on what I am missing, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: That is the whole point of binding. Your bind a collection to it with which it gets filled with items. That happens runtime, so you won't see the items design time.
Define 'didn't work', do you get an error? Are there no items? If the binding fails you should see some errors in the output window. If you don't see any errors; are there items in your collection?

Comment: @GeraldVersluis by "didn't work" I mean that the combobox is empty.  As for items in my collection, Ok now I am getting somewhere!  So instead of putting my comboboxitem contents inside of my xaml combobox code, I need to create a list?

Comment: Yes. As said, binding means you have a collection (list if you will) somewhere and you bind it to a control (combobox in this case) then runtime the combobox gets filled with the items on that list (that is what you specify by the ItemSource property, set it to {Binding <yourcollectionobject>}) if your list is empty, no items will show up! So do something like @David said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the values in your `Group` collection somewhere (in the initializer or the class constructor I'd say):

```
Groups.Add("Data Warehouse");
Groups.Add("Data KPI");
Groups.Add("Data Failures");
Groups.Add("Data All Groups");
```

frankly, I do not see the point of doing this in this case, but It might have something to do with the rest of your code.

Answer (score 2):

like David said - fill your Groups collection. second: be sure that you set your **DataContext** to an instance of your viewmodel. your binding for the itemssource is right. the binding for the SelectedItem is not right: you can just bind to a string property. Mode=TwoWay its just needed when the selection should also be done from the viewmodel.

```
 public string MySelectedItem
 {
   get{return this._myselecteditem;}
   set{this._myselecteditem=value; OnPropertyChanged("MySelectedItem");}
 }
```

xaml

```
  <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}" SelectedItem="{Binding MySelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: you should also check your vs output window for binding errors or use tools like Snoop.